# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'data' (T_STRING), expecting ']' on line 33

Tags: php, битрикс

Написал программу на **php**:

```
    <section style="margin-top: 40px;">
    <div class="grid-container">
        <div class="grid-x grid-padding-x">
            <div class="cell large-12">
                <h1><?=$arFields['NAME'];?></h1>
                 <?php
                    $file = CFile::ResizeImageGet($arFields['PREVIEW_PICTURE'], array('width' => 300, 'height' => 300), BX_RESIZE_IMAGE_PROPORTIONAL, true);
                    ?> <img src="<?= $file['src']; ?>">
                <p><?= $arFields['PREVIEW_TEXT']; ?>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <a target="_blank" href="http://<?=$arFields[">"data-bx-app-ex-href="http://<?=$arFields["PROPERTY_LINK_VALUE"]" ?> &gt; <?=$arFields["PROPERTY_LINK_VALUE"];?></a>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
     </section>
```

Но не могу понять, в чем дело, строка 33: `<a target="_blank" href="http://<?=$arFields[">"data-bx-app-ex-href="http://<?=$arFields["PROPERTY_LINK_VALUE"]" ?> &gt; <?=$arFields["PROPERTY_LINK_VALUE"];?></a>` на строке 33. Буду благодарен.

Comment: нельзя использовать двойные кавычки в двойных кавычках при выводе серверного кода (и не только). IDE которую использует как правило всегда подсвечивает такую ошибку. Если только вы не в блокноте пишите

Comment: `<?=$arFields[">`  так забыли `"] ?>` дописать или что вы там планировали сделать-то? у вас начинается вывод какой-то переменной, и происходит какая то непонятная ситуация. посмотрите на этот фрагмент, и решите, что там должно быть

Comment: @DmitriiSedov двойные кавычки внутри двойных кавычек, очевидно, требуют экранирования, но никто не запрещает их использовать